# save custom camera capture image iOS Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, camera, save

I am new to iPhone, I want to save image into the album & I want that image path.
I did this already.

Now, I want a custom name for image & store image with that name.
I used below code but I am not getting any image into the album.

Can anybody guide me where am I wrong ?

```
#pragma mark - Image Picker Controller delegate methods

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

     UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.imageView.image = chosenImage;

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];



// Todo to use custom name comment this line.
 //UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.imageView.image,nil,nil,nil);

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"];
    UIImage *image = imageView.image; // imageView is my image from camera
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];



  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
    });
}
```

Comment: i think its not Possible.why you are do like this?what is your goal to add name of your custom image?

Comment: @sohil. this is client requirement to store image with cient1, client2 etc. weather should I follow , suggestion but confused on call for image.

Comment: You want to store image in Photo Gallery or Personal Document Directory?

Comment: I want to store image with custom name. which ever way is easy. Personal or Gallery.

Comment: if you have store image with your custom name you want to store image on Document Directory

Comment: will you write objective c answer for me. I am facing issue into path the swift answer as bellow. Objective c answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132556/discussion-between-sohil-and-novusmobile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Store Image with Custom name like this :

```
UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

//save image in Document Derectory
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSLog(@"Get Path : %@",documentsDirectory);

//create Folder if Not Exist
  NSError *error = nil;
  NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/MyFolder"];

  if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
       [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]; //Create folder

     NSString *customePhotoName=@"MyPhotoName";
     NSString* path= [dataPath stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@.png",customePhotoName]];
     NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(chosenImage);

     [imageData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
     NSLog(@"Save Image Path : %@",path);
```

Comment: Thank you. I already upvoted this. if this will work. I will accept this.

Comment: I checked my iPhone. I didn't get a photo. where to see capture image ?
I need to use same UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum ??

Comment: @NovusMobile it will not store on your iphone Photo Gallary it is store on Document Directory Folder. if you want to store image on photo library than 'UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);' than Write this code but it will not show image Name on Photos.

Comment: can you explain me what is requirement for custom name?

Comment: done thank you @Sohil. accepting answer. hope you can do the same for question.

Answer (score 1):

In one of my project I did this:

```
let directory = "yourDirectoryName"
let fileName = "file.png"
let directoryPath = NSHomeDirectory() + "/Library/Caches/\(directory)"
do {
    try NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(directoryPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)?.writeToFile(directoryPath+fileName), atomically: true)
} catch let error as NSError {}
```

Code works in Swift 2.3. I hope, this is what you want.

Comment: Yes. but Shall I call this after the didfinishPickingMediawithInfo function or anywhere else?

Comment: Yes I use it inside the didfinishPickingMediawithInfo function

Answer (score 1):

Verify if NSData and UIImage objects are proper, set "atomically" as YES, check out the below code I use:

```
//Save your image with a completion selector
 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);

 //Completion selector
- (void) image: (UIImage *) image
 didFinishSavingWithError: (NSError *) error
    contextInfo: (void *) contextInfo 
   {
       if(error)
     {
    NSLog(@"save error :%@", [error localizedDescription]);

     }
      else if (!error)
     {
            PHAsset *asset = [self fetchImageAsset];
     }
 }

    //Fetch image based on create date or whatever naming system you follow
- (nullable PHAsset *)fetchImageAsset
 {
        PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:YES]];
        PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:fetchOptions];
        PHAsset *lastAsset = [fetchResult lastObject];
        return lastAsset;

    }
```

Comment: I am very new to this. but I didn't get your point . I understood first part to save UIImageWriteToSavedPhotoAlbum but didn't get anything else. I think I need to study more about iPhone class first.Thanks for your answer. 
Does this run after didfinishmetho...

Comment: "Selector" simply means a function and "completion selector " means the method which will run on your task completion. You could pass this method name in "UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum" as a parameter and you will be able  get the error(NSError) while writing the image to the specified path might get to know whats wrong. Also PHAsset is an objective c class used for media assets while saving and fetching. Please up vote. cheers !

Comment: Do you have any reference for the iPhone tutorials for beginner?

Comment: Go to youtube and check out "Stanford university iOS" channel, they are in Swift language now however all the old "Objective-c" ones are also available in iTunes channel for free. You should have a basic idea of object oriented programming: Link: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYVp6suz7ztKAKY8jpfACXA